# Create method that returns associated object's attribute value if current object's attribute is nil (jsonb type)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following two classes:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns
  # ...
  # features :jsonb

  has_one :plan
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns
  # ...
  # features :jsonb
end
```

And will be calling features like this:

```
account.features    # being account is an instance of Account
# or
account.features[:feature_key]
```

The thing is I want `account` to look for `features` or `features[:feature_key]` within itself, and if that is `nil` or `empty` it should pick the value from the associated `Plan` object.

Something like:

```
features.present? ? features : plan.features
# and
features[:feature_key].present ? features[:feature_key] : plan.features[:feature_key]
```

But in a proper method within `Account` class

Comment: Have you tried putting this in an instance method?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not best practice, but you can override the getter with a custom method. In your case:

```
def features
  return features[:feature_key] if features[:feature_key].present?
  return plan&.features[:feature_key] if plan&.features[:feature_key].present?
end
```

Not sure that's the logic you need, but that'll work for an override if you put it in the `Account` model. The preferred way to do it would be to name the method something else and call that method so you can still access the unmodified attribute if need be.

Comment: thanks @NM Pennypacker, but that method is not receiving [:key], that would never work.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand but given your comment under the other answer I am assuming you are looking for something like:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base 

  def feature_info(key)
    return plan.features[key] unless features.present? && features[key].present?
    features[key]
  end 
end
```

Then called as

```
   account = Account.first
   account.feature_info(:feature_key)
```

This might be cleaner though

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def features 
    read_attribute(:features) || {} 
  end
  def feature_info(key)
    return plan.features[key] unless features[key].present?
    features[key]
  end 
end
```